# Jackson build JSON from values, term?

Tags: java, json, jackson

The documentation in Jackson is horrible and it only states how it is possible to create JSON from objects and streams, not piece by piece. I cannot find the term to be able to search for more examples/documentation.

I would like to do something like the following.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject().add("type", "unregister").add("id",id);
return jsonObject.toString();
```

Which would return `{"type":"unregister","id":2}` as an example. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Because it's not possible to create JSON piece by piece.

Comment: @OrangeDog Do you mean through Jackson? That's wrong. You definitely can.

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding `JsonObject` in Jackson is [`ObjectNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html). You can use its various [`xyzNode(...)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ContainerNode.html#textNode%28java.lang.String%29) factory methods to produce [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) subtype instances. You can then use [`ObjectNode#set(String, JsonNode)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html#set%28java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode%29) to add them.

```
JsonNodeFactory nc = new JsonNodeFactory(false); // or true, depending
ObjectNode root = new ObjectNode(nc);
TextNode text = root.textNode("unregister");
NumericNode id = root.numberNode(2);

root.set("type", text);
root.set("id", id);
```

Then

```
System.out.println(node);
```

produces

```
{"type":"unregister","id":2}
```

---

You can also create an `ObjectNode` through the `ObjectMapper` which uses the `ObjectMapper`'s `JsonNodeFactory`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode root = mapper.createObjectNode();
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson maps Java Objects to JSON, so their documentation is telling you what it does (it does not provide a sort of *builder API* to arbitrarily compose JSON documents)

If you want to map arbitrary key/values, use a `Map<String, Object>` and use Jackson to turn it into JSON.  You can mix heterogeneous map values and get the result you want this way, pseudo:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("type", "unregister");
map.put("id", id);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(sw, map); // mapper is a ObjectMapper instance
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

Comment: Jackson does provide such an API, even if it doesn't document it very deeply. Serializing a `Map<String, Object>` is kind of overdoing it when `ObjectNode` is available.

Comment: I would have to disagree here about *overdoing it*, now you're talking about tying the data representation into a specific api (the Jackson API), where the data (at least in my opinion) is better represented in a generic model (i.e. a `Map`).  If his data is not contained in some encapsulating model already, then the resulting code would be very specifically tied to the Jackson API

Comment: I meant overdoing it given the fact that `ObjectNode` exists. Serializing a `Map<String,Object>` is relatively expensive, while serializing an `ObjectNode` is trivial.